# wpf how to get program focus form windows

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio, focus

i made program it work in background, i want this program only work on program i select it
example : i created Auto clicker and i want to use this program just in games if the user go to any other program it doesn't work

this way i hope it is there

```
if(Windows.Focus.NameProgram.ToString() == "Call of Duty Cold War")
{
   // here all commands i will put it later.
}
```

here i mean what windows focus it now if it is Call of Duty Cold War then work, if not dont work (of course still running in the background)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function called `GetForegroundWindow` from Windows API.

The implementation further down gets the current focused window.

Documentation: [GetForegroundWindow | MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

```
   public class GetFocusedWindow
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

        private static string GetActiveWindowTitle()
        {
            const int nChars = 256;
            StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
            IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();

            if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
            {
                return Buff.ToString();
            }
            return null;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.WriteLine(GetActiveWindowTitle());
            }
        }
    }
```